# Type 'Interface' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm building a Vue app and I'm trying to iterate over an array of "Poliza" which is an interface I created.

Turns out that TS thinks I'm trying to assign this custom type I created to a string,number or symbol. I've researched for hours trying to understand this error but I can't find an answer.

Why is this happening? How do I solve it?

```js
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      polizas: [] as Poliza[],
      poliza: {} as Poliza,
      token: ""
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async getPolizas() {
      axios.get(`https://localhost:7006/api/Pagos/All`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log(response.data)
          this.polizas = response.data
        }
      });
    },
  },

  beforeMount() {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem("token")!;
    console.log(this.token);
    this.getPolizas(); 
  },
});

interface Poliza {
  id: number
  name: string
  tipo: string
  vigente: boolean
  idUsuario: number
}
```

```html
<div :v-for="poliza in polizas" :key="poliza.id" class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell">123456</div>
  <div class="table-cell">SALUD</div>
  <div class="table-cell">VIGENTE</div>
  <div class="table-cell"><button>Descargar</button></div>
</div>
```

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra colon in your v-for attribute, it should be `v-for`, not `:v-for`